# Set Up and Share This Image Folder at Backend API side?

Tags: node.js

Have a nodejs backend API project accepting avatar upload as below and working great:

server.js:

```
const myupload = require('./useformidable');
app.post('/uploads', myUpload);
```

useformidable.js:

```
const IncomingForm = require('formidable').IncomingForm;
var ImgFolder = new IncomingForm({ uploadDir: 'C:\\somewhere\\AvatarUpload' }); // corresponding to 'http://localhost:3000/uploads'
```

Two questions:

1. Frontend app (can be Angular or .NET) will do things like `<img src="/avatar/avatarFileName">` to show avatar. So in this nodejs project, how to set up a path/virtual folder corresponding to `/avatar`?
2. `formidable` renames all uploaded files to a scrambled name like `upload_088357d045e6ebbc344bf934ea97c393` (even for the same source file name). So it may not be easy to guess a new name, but I'm concerned with security, any suggestion?

Comment: Probably more for name collision avoidance.  Otherwise every upload of `Thumbnail.jpg` would overwrite the previous.  Is the API not telling you what it renamed the file to?

Comment: @zero298 already confirmed same source file name won't get the same new name by `formidable`. API does provide back the new file name. I need to setup an `avatar` virtual folder at node side so any frontend can refer to it, just don't know how.

Comment: I know how to set up proxy for frontend so they know where to go for `/avatar`. For example I can point it to `http://localhost:3000/avatar` It's the backend at node, I don't know how to set up a virtual folder/path `avatar` corresponds to `C:\somewhere\AvatarUpload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wants to know how, combining 1 and 2:

For security reason, it's better to move uploaded to a more restrict folder, say `allavatar`. So, in backend `server.js` file:

```
var allavatarimgdir = require('path').join(__dirname, '/allavatar');
app.use('/allavatar', express.static(allavatarimgdir));
```

then in angular,

first add following `proxyConfig` option to **angular.json** like:

```
"serve": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "UI:build",

              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
```

second **proxy.conf.js**

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = 
[
    {
        context: 
        [
            "/allavatar",      
        ],
        "target" : "http://localhost:3000", 
        "secure": false, 
        "changeOrigin": true, 
        "logLevel": "debug"  //"info": prints out in console
    }
]
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```